# Notice: Undefined index in XAMPP V3.2.1

Tags: php, indexing, xampp, undefined

I just installed the newest version of XAMPP and am getting `Notice: Undefined index:` for any variable with `$_POST` or `$_GET` i tried to turn error reporting off for notices but it did not change anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to fix this.

1. Check if the variable is set by surrounding the `$_POST` with `isset()`
2. Add `error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE)` to the first line of your script.

This type of error is not important inside of php and is just a warning letting you know that you did not check if it was set.

Answer (score 0):

You should always make use of the **`isset`** construct before checking the values of **`$_POST`** or **`$_GET`** values..

Something like this..

```
<?php
if(!isset($_GET['id']))
{
echo "Value was not passed or set. Let me go and check the form !";
}
```

Comment: I know this but the issue is that a variable `$some_var = $_POST['fdsaf']` gives me this error not a isset

Comment: Without your code we can't help.. Have you tried that surrounding your code with the `isset` construct ? `if(isset($_POST['fdsaf'])` ....

Comment: `var_dump($_POST);` before this and check if it returns the POST value you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

What @Shankar said is true, but Notice errors are not important in php , you can turn them of easily without any problem by putting

```
 error_reporting(E_ALL ^ E_NOTICE)
```

in the first line of your application.

[**Refrence**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)